# I need some lib in js to show 3d models

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, 3d, render

I need a lib in js to create 3D geometric forms than show in a div like this.
Can gerate some jpg or something like that!
[3d cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMTuV.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Use
Three.js to make a 3D Scene in React.js
, God bless you